# how to change color on Mouse over leaflet-react?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geojson

i'm facing a problem of mouseover event in leaflet
the thing is , when i hover ,the weight of the city changes for 2s and it doesn't stay highlighted even though the mouse is over the city
here is my code :

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    const { name, CWILAYA } = e.target.feature.properties;
    setSelected({
        name: name,
        CWILAYA: CWILAYA

    });
    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 6,// change the weight  of  a state 
        fillOpacity: 1
    });
    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,// call the function when mouseover  
        });
```

[image]

could you please help me !
thank you

Comment: try strokeWidth style instead of weight

Comment: the thing is , when i hover ,the weight of the city changes for 2s and it doesn't stay highlighted even though the mouse is over the city

Comment: did you get the solution ? if yes then please share i am also facing same issue

Comment: Same here, Did you find a solution? ?