# React-leaflet my entite doesn't hightlight when clicking

Tags: reactjs, highlight, react-leaflet

I've got the same issue than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181455/how-to-change-color-on-mouse-over-leaflet-react) but, there is no answer on it so I'll try ot my way :
I follow the [following tutorial](https://fmuchembi.medium.com/let-us-build-a-choropleth-map-using-react-leaflet-together-3245d30ac900) to create a chloroplète map with react-leaflet. Everything is doing great (the import of GeoJSON data, the colors etc.). but when I use the function OnEachFeature the highlight function doens't work.
When I click I have the informations than appaear but the border is not getting bigger like I configure it :

Before clicking on an entite
[image: Before clikcing on an entite]

Afeter clicking on an entite
[image: After clicking on an entite]

There is my code :

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet'
import data from  '../GeoJSON/data_exemple_PRA.json';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

function CarteRisquesPRACour() {
    const [onselect, setOnselect] = useState({});
    /* function determining what should happen onmouseover, this function updates our state*/
    const highlightFeature = (e=> {
        const { risques7, libelle } = e.target.feature.properties;
        e.target.setStyle({
            strokeWidth: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
        setOnselect({
            risques:risques7,
            libelle:libelle,
        });
    });
    /*resets our state i.e no properties should be displayed when a feature is not clicked or hovered over */
    const resetHighlight= (e =>{
        setOnselect({});
        e.target.setStyle(style(e.target.feature));
    })
    /* this function is called when a feature in the map is hovered over or when a mouse moves out of it, the function calls two functions
     highlightFeature and resetHighlight*/
    const onEachFeature= (feature, layer)=> {
        layer.on({
            click: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight
        });
    }

    const getColorRisVulne=(d => {
        return  d > 3500 ? '#530d0d' :
                d > 2750 ? '#530d0d' :
                d > 2500 ? '#69120e' :
                d > 2000 ? '#7f1810' :
                d > 1750 ? '#941d11' :
                d > 1500 ? '#aa2213' :
                d > 1000 ? '#c02714' :
                d > 750 ? '#cb3915' :
                d > 670 ? '#cf5315' :
                d > 650 ? '#d36e15' :
                d > 600 ? '#d78815' :
                d > 520 ? '#dba215' :
                d > 490 ? '#debd15' :
                d > 465 ? '#e2d715' :
                d > 430 ? '#d6d616' :
                d > 400 ? '#c7ce17' :
                d > 360 ? '#b7c517' :
                d > 320 ? '#a8bd18' :
                d > 275 ? '#98b519' :
                d > 210 ? '#89ad1a' :
                d > 190 ? '#6f9917' :
                d > 165 ? '#558415' :
                d > 140 ? '#3b6f12' :
                d > 110 ? '#205a10' :
                d > 0 ? '#06450e' :
                '#ffffff'; //le dernier on ne met pas son nom car le reste
    })
    const style = (feature => {
        return ({
            weight: 0.5,
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#000000',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColorRisVulne(feature.properties.risques7)
        });
    });
    const feature = data.features.map(feature=>{
        return(feature);
    });
    return(
        <div className="totalCarte">
            <div className="">
                {!onselect.risques && (
                <div className='paragraphe infos_carte'>
                    Cliquez sur une zone pour avoir plus de détails
                </div>
                )}
                {onselect.risques && (
                    <div className='paragraphe infos_carte' >
                        {onselect.libelle} : {onselect.risques} €/ha
                    </div>
                )}
                <MapContainer center={[48.832,2.623]} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={false} >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    <GeoJSON data={feature}
                    style={style} 
                    onEachFeature={onEachFeature}/>
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default CarteRisquesPRACour;
```

Can someone help me understand why ?

Comment: Do you have a demo with your code so far? it is not easy to reproduce it with the given code. Anything can be wrong. or instance in your style function you have syntax errors. If you return an object it should be return { otherwide you should remove return and do => ({...})

Comment: Hey I don't think I understand your comment, what do you mean by a demo ? when I run my code I don't have any error message.

Comment: a codesandbox or stackblitz with a minimum repdrocubile example of your attempt so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to an answer of @TomazicM in StackExchange , I modify my code so that it can work,

1. I transforme all my const into function
2. I put all the general function before my component like getColoreRisVulne ans style
3. I surrounded my  with {data&&( )}

the corrected code is in here :

With that it works perfectly with a mouseover or a click

````js
import React from 'react';
import {TileLayer, GeoJSON, MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet'
import data from  '../GeoJSON/data_exemple_PRA.json';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

let mapRef;

function getColorRisVulne(d) {
    return  d > 3500 ? '#530d0d' :
            d > 2750 ? '#530d0d' :
            d > 2500 ? '#69120e' :
            d > 2000 ? '#7f1810' :
            d > 1750 ? '#941d11' :
            d > 1500 ? '#aa2213' :
            d > 1000 ? '#c02714' :
            d > 750 ? '#cb3915' :
            d > 670 ? '#cf5315' :
            d > 650 ? '#d36e15' :
            d > 600 ? '#d78815' :
            d > 520 ? '#dba215' :
            d > 490 ? '#debd15' :
            d > 465 ? '#e2d715' :
            d > 430 ? '#d6d616' :
            d > 400 ? '#c7ce17' :
            d > 360 ? '#b7c517' :
            d > 320 ? '#a8bd18' :
            d > 275 ? '#98b519' :
            d > 210 ? '#89ad1a' :
            d > 190 ? '#6f9917' :
            d > 165 ? '#558415' :
            d > 140 ? '#3b6f12' :
            d > 110 ? '#205a10' :
            d > 0 ? '#06450e' :
            '#ffffff'; //le dernier on ne met pas son nom car le reste
    }

function style(feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: getColorRisVulne(feature.properties.risques7),
    weight: 0.5,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#000000',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
  };
}

function CarteRisquesPRACour() {
  const [onselect, setOnselect] = React.useState({});

  function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    const { risques7, libelle} = e.target.feature.properties;
    setOnselect({
        risques:risques7,
        libelle:libelle,
    });
    layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
  }
  function resetHighlight(e) {
    setOnselect({});
    e.target.setStyle(style(e.target.feature));
  }
  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      click: highlightFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="totalCarte">
        <div className="">
        {!onselect.risques && (
        <div className='paragraphe infos_carte'>
            Cliquez sur une zone pour avoir plus de détails
        </div>
        )}
        {onselect.risques && (
            <div className='paragraphe infos_carte' >
                {onselect.libelle} : {onselect.risques} €/ha
            </div>
        )}
        <MapContainer
          zoom={10}
          scrollWheelZoom={false}
          maxZoom={14}
          center={[48.832,2.623]}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {data && (
            <GeoJSON data={data} 
            style={style} 
            onEachFeature={onEachFeature} />
          )}
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
export default CarteRisquesPRACour;
```
````